# MySQL wont create table as I want

Tags: mysql

When I create table, MySQL changes everything except row names.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
table_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(table_id),
table_1 varchar(45),
table_2 varchar(45),
table_3 varchar(999),
table_4 varchar(45)
)"
```

MySQL sets everything primary except `table_id` and sets everything unique, index and full text.

If I make my custom table everything goes on random mode. Something is primary, something unique.

I'm on shared hosting on asmallorange.com.

```
CREATE TABLE `MY_TABLE` (  `table_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `table_1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  `table_2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  `table_3` varchar(999) DEFAULT NULL,  `table_4` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`table_id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is `SHOW CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE`

I'm using phpAdmin 3.5.5.

Comment: I don't see this happening on my server. Could you include output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE` so as to present the problem?

Comment: How do you know that all becomes unique and etc.?

Comment: `everything unique, index and full text` - no it is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
`table_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`table_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Here is an example of creating table with different fields.

Comment: Everything was allright, tables were ok and working. Then i tried add one field and that table was messed up. Then i tried create random tables like that one in question, and weird things continued.

Comment: @starizec, for us to be able to answer your question, you must provide with some data to work with. What "weird things continued"? Please provide with sample query that went wrong. Please provide with output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE".